# Completely empty content database

Tags: wss-3.0, database, content-database

Anyone come across the following issue?

WSS3 installation using WID, the content database for the site was empty. All of the tables were there but each table was empty, AllUserData, Sites, etc. Allll empty, and as a result sharepoint was not working. Fortunately, last night's backup was successful and restored the missing data.

The network admin is reviewing access logs to the server and hoping to compile a short list of users who may have access the database.

Have you seen something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we never discovered what caused it, but restoring from backup saved it.